# How to get antivirus details on Windows Server in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I have been asked by my company to get antivirus details from our machines using Windows apps in C#.

I used WMI to get antivirus details from the workstation OS, such as Windows 10.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\SecurityCenter2", "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");

ManagementObjectCollection data = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in data)
{
    if (queryObj["displayName"] != null)
    {
        string antivirusName = queryObj["displayName"].ToString();
    }
     if (queryObj["productState"] != null)
    {
       string productState = queryObj["productState"].ToString();
    }
}
```

But the thing is, there are no classes such as root\SecurityCenter2 or root\SecurityCenter present in Windows servers. But how can I fetch antivirus information from the server machine? Please guide me